# How to use globalCompositeOperation with three images?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

How can I place a blue box between red and green one using this function?

I need to achieve this effect.

[image]

Here's a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Alexnotonfire/pen/wKXERY).

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="canvas">
</canvas>
```

**JS**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

window.onload = draw;

green = new Image;
green.src = 'http://www.thebouncingbox.com/images/thumbnail/produkte/large/California-Sunbounce-meterware-green-box.jpg';

red = new Image;
red.src = 'http://www.front-porch-ideas-and-more.com/image-files/color-red.jpg';

blue = new Image;
blue.src = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/colorcombos-images/colors/000066.png';

function draw() {
 ctx.drawImage(green, 0, 0, 200, 200);
 ctx.drawImage(red, 80, 50, 120, 100);
  ctx.drawImage(blue, 60, 30, 100, 100);
}
```

Comment: Move the red to the last, so it'll draw above blue and green. [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwzMNj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not change the order you draw them?

```
function draw() {
ctx.drawImage(green, 0, 0, 200, 200);
ctx.drawImage(blue, 60, 30, 100, 100);   
ctx.drawImage(red, 80, 50, 120, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> You need to listen `onload` event of the image before drawing it. To have images over image, series operation will help!

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
window.onload = draw1;

function draw1() {
  var green = new Image();
  green.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(green, 0, 0, 200, 200);
    draw2();
  };
  green.src = 'http://www.thebouncingbox.com/images/thumbnail/produkte/large/California-Sunbounce-meterware-green-box.jpg';
}

function draw2() {
  var blue = new Image;
  blue.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(blue, 50, 50, 100, 100);
    draw3();
  };
  blue.src = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/colorcombos-images/colors/000066.png';

}

function draw3() {
  var red = new Image();
  red.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(red, 100, 100, 100, 100);
  };
  red.src = 'http://www.front-porch-ideas-and-more.com/image-files/color-red.jpg';
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```